# find index/offset base on specific id

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, api, pagination

I want to do pagination for api/ajax, 
if use page 1, page 2 type .. could be duplicate row, if new row just create.

So I see how instagram api doing and tried below,

first request:
use query 1
read first row offset parameter is zero and return `pagination` data for ajax to request next

```
"pagination": {
  "prev_end_id": ..,
  "count": ...
}
```

request next:
use query 2
If order by `id` or `price_number` is `integer`, I will return  `prev_end_id` or `prev_end_price` , check `desc` or `asc` , then select smaller or bigger.
But if order by `name` `string` or other type column, how to do it?

Am I doing correct,  is there better way to solve this?

Should I ignore order by which column, just return `end_id`,
when request next,
find offset base on id, then do same as first request?
is so how to find offset base on id?
Select all rows and loop rows find the specific id index? sounds poor performance...

```
1
SELECT
  p.* 
  FROM product p 
    ORDER BY p.id desc NULLS LAST OFFSET $1 LIMIT $2
2
SELECT
  p.* 
  FROM product p 
  WHERE p.id < $1
    ORDER BY p.id desc NULLS LAST LIMIT $2

1
SELECT
  p.* 
  FROM product p 
    ORDER BY p.name desc NULLS LAST OFFSET $1 LIMIT $2
2
SELECT
  p.* 
  FROM product p 
  AND p.price_number < $1
    ORDER BY p.name desc NULLS LAST LIMIT $2


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "product"(
  "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
  "name" varchar DEFAULT NULL,
  "name_slug" varchar DEFAULT NULL,
  "price_number" numeric DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *keyset pagination*, because `OFFSET` is a performance problem and can lead to weird results if new data are added concurrently (as you have observed).

If `sort_key` is the field by which the results are ordered, the first query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product
ORDER BY sort_key
LIMIT 50;
```

Then you remember the biggest returned `sort_key`, no matter if it's an integer or a string, as `<last_key>`.
Your second query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product
WHERE sort_key > <last_key>
ORDER BY sort_key
LIMIT 50;
```

and so on until you are done.

For efficiency, create an index on `sort_key`.

You can find this method described [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

Comment: Thanks for reply, this seems same as my example in question? my problem is if the column datatype is string  not integer then how to make it become sort_key < last_key

Comment: Yes, I had the impression that you had considered this possibility in your question, but your examples were so hard to read that I thought it best to be explicit. Strings should be no problem, the method works for any data type that allows comparisons, and string certainly does.

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try this!!